# Is it better to store all comments for everything in one table or have multiple tables?

Tags: mysql

Lets say you have 3 or 4 site features like photos, videos, wall posts, etc.  And each have the ability for you to leave a comment.

Should the DB have 1 table and insert all those comments in that one table with their respective unique IDs or should they have like 3 or 4 other tables like Photo_table, video_table, etc....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Better to put them in single table and add respective unique IDs of different features with one extra column `type` (Because ids from those master tables can be same)  which will indicate whether this comment is from `Photo`,`video` or anything else.

Suppose if project grow in future have some more features ie (10 features) then you do not have to create tables for all these.

Comment: I agree. Whenever I find myself creating identical tables that just differ in name, I stop, and just create one with a "type" field as well.

Comment: you haven't explained why it is better.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement it in a number of ways. If a comment has the same basic fields in all cases, you would probably have an easier time using one table. If the comments have different data depending on the type of comment, it would be easier to separate them out.

Answer (score 1):

Sourav,

Speed will not be an issue if there an index tag on the "Comment type" field. Less number of tables is good for data maintenance.

Answer (score -1):

It woule be better to use 3 different table photos_comment, wall_comment,... coz it will speed up the look up process when showing comments for photos and will help you to manage the db too

Comment: having one table and using index is more appropriate and is easier to maintain.